# Converting from java to c++, what is the equivalent curl command for setRequestProperty

Tags: java, c++, curl, curlpp

I'm trying to convert a Java application to C++, I am using cURL for my requests.
Below is the java code; I'm wondering how to replicate the `connection.setRequestProperty()` method.

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
String userId= =getUserId()
connection.setRequestProperty("UserID", userId);
```

Below is my current code that does not work.

```
struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
curl_slist_append(headers, "UserID="2"); 

curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,headers); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, certDataPath.c_str());
CURLcode c =curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, postRequestCallback);
```

Below is a the java servlet code that is failing (id is null or empty)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
...
...
String ud = request.getHeader("UserID");
}
```

What is the equiv command to `setRequestProperty` in cURL.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be your header string format is off, how about:

curl_slist_append(headers, "UserID: 2");

ah, you need to assign the result, so

headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "UserID: 2");

Comment: Ok, I tried curl_slist_append(headers, "UserID: 2"); unfortunately same result.

Comment: headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "UserID: 2"); - fixed my issue ,thanks